# Python difficulties with lists and loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have this code that gives me weird errors. Below you should see that code.
First of i have my CombatEngine that basically just simulates a shoot out between me the player and the list of enemies. In the class TheBridge i make a instance of the combatengine and give it a list of enemies in the constructor(i code mostly in c#) but when i run the the combat method on the engine an error will be returned

**AttributeError: type object 'GothonTrooper' has no attribute 'health'**

I really dont understand how that is possible when its clear that health is defined for the GothonTrooper class. I suppose the error occurs in the combat method itself some point around when the individual enemy is found from the randint function.

```
class TheBridge(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        enemies = [GothonTrooper(), GothonTrooper(), GothonTrooper(), GothonTrooper, GothonTrooper()]
        self.the_bridge_combat = CombatEngine(enemies)

        ...


class CombatEngine(object):
    def __init__(self, enemies):
        self.enemies = enemies

    while len(self.enemies) != 0:       
        enemy = self.enemies[randint(0, len(self.enemies)-1)] 
        print "You shoot at the Gothon." 
        hit_or_miss = PLAYER.attack() 
        if hit_or_miss >= 5:
            print "The shot hits the Gothon!"
            enemy.health -= 10
            print "The Gothon is down to %s health" % enemy.health
        ...


class GothonTrooper(Humanoid):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100

    def attack(self):
        return randint(1,10)
```

Comment: Can you please show the full traceback?

Comment: Is it a typo that you did not include the parenthesis for one of your `GothonTrooper` in your `enemies` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you have provided in your code is not a typo, the missing `()` in one of your `GothonTrooper` objects in your `enemies` list is the culprit. Without it, that object is never instatiated. Therefore that item will not yet have the `health` attribute.

To better illustrate where the problem is stemming from, the below example uses the [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) method to return properties available on that object, (notice that `health` is missing on the second `print` line)

```
>>> class Trooper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = "90%"


>>> enemies = [Trooper(), Trooper]
>>> for enemy in enemies:
       print(dir(enemy))


[..., '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'health']
[..., '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

Comment: What a blunder Im not used to be able to do that in C#, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,my English is poor. Look at your define,the fourth `GothonTrooper` don't have `()` ,so as to
`AttributeError:` type object `GothonTrooper` has no attribute `health`

```
enemies = [GothonTrooper(), GothonTrooper(), GothonTrooper(), GothonTrooper, GothonTrooper()]
```

Comment: thanks for the help it did indeed fix my issue but i gave the answer to Anthony as he was the first with the answer